# How to make 2 columns with information that is iterated in React using Material-UI

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui, grid

I am making a component using Grid. What I want to happen is that the information shows up in two columns instead of just the one I am getting. I am not sure how to achieve this, I know if I could add another Grid section with another sm={6} that is would populate with two columns, but I don't have another bit of information to put inside another Grid as it is all coming from my map function.

```
const renderData = (person, picture, index) => {
        return (
            <Paper className={classes.Paper}>
                <img src={person.picture.large} />
            </Paper>
        )
    }
return (
        <div className={classes.sectionContainer}>
            <h3 className={classes.title}>Follow our instagram!</h3>
            <h3 className={classes.title}>@platformdanceshowcase</h3>
            <Grid container spacing={1}>
                {previewData.slice(0, visible).map(renderData)}
            </Grid>
            <Container className={classes.extendButtonArea}>
                {visible < previewData.length && (
                    <Button className={classes.extendButton} onClick={loadMore}>
                        View More...
                    </Button>
                )}
            </Container>
        </div>
    )
}
```

any help you could provide on this topic would be greatly appreciated as I have spun myself into a corner with this one. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Link to another copy of this question which has an answer that actually answers the underlying question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66819991

Answer (score 0):

Following the doc, Columns are  components with the `item` props. It replace the container props that is used in the Parent.

Example:

```js
<Grid container spacing={1}>
   {previewData.slice(0, visible).map((person, picture, index) => (
      <Grid item key={index}>...</Grid>
   )}
</Grid>
```

I don't use Material ui so try it.

Src :
https://material-ui.com/components/grid/

Comment: Yes, I understand that. Originally I had the grid with item sm={6}... but it was still only displaying a one column grid, as a test I added another grid item sm={6}. Which worked, it made two columns, but because I am iterating with a map function to create the data inside the column, I cannot call on my map function twice because it just displays 2 columns but with the same information in both. So back to my question, how to make the grid display two columns when you only have one map to iterate off of?

Answer (score 0):

In the Material UI documentation there's the following example:

```
<Grid container spacing={{ xs: 2, md: 3 }} columns={{ xs: 4, sm: 8, md: 12 }}>
  {Array.from(Array(6)).map((_, index) => (
    <Grid item xs={2} sm={4} md={4} key={index}>
      <Item>xs=2</Item>
    </Grid>
  ))}
</Grid>
```