# How to make 2 columns with React and Material-UI Grid with only one map to iterate over

Tags: css, reactjs, dictionary, material-ui, grid

I am using Material-UI Grid. What I’m trying to do is display the information iterated from my map function in two columns. However, currently it is only displaying in 1 column. As a test I added another Grid item sm={6} and used same map function. The 2 columns were achieved however both columns are displaying the exact same information. My question is how do you break a grid into two columns when there is only 1 map function to iterate off of?

```
const renderData = (person, picture, index) => {
        return (
            <Paper className={classes.Paper}>
                <img src={person.picture.large} />
            </Paper>
        )
    }
return (
        <div className={classes.sectionContainer}>
            <h3 className={classes.title}>Follow our instagram!</h3>
            <h3 className={classes.title}>@platformdanceshowcase</h3>
            <Grid direction='row' container spacing={1}>
               <Grid item sm={6}>
                {previewData.slice(0, visible).map(renderData)}
               </Grid>
            </Grid>
            <Container className={classes.extendButtonArea}>
                {visible < previewData.length && (
                    <Button className={classes.extendButton} onClick={loadMore}>
                        View More...
                    </Button>
                )}
            </Container>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Any help that can be provided would be greatly appreciated. I have walked myself in a circle and am further confusing myself, so thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's hard to tell exactly what you're looking to do from the question, maybe you could markup a screenshot or provide a little sketch of what you're trying to achieve?

I'm not really sure why you have 2 return functions in your renderData component, but I'm going to interpret the first as representative of the elements of the previewData array and the second as the columns element you describe in the question.

My interpretation of your question is that you want two columns side by side that are rendering data in previewData from index 0 to visible. One way to achieve that might be to modify your code like this:

```
<Grid direction='row' container spacing={1}>
    <Grid container item sm={6}>
        {previewData.slice(0, visible).map((renderData, i) => 
            i % 2 == 0 ? renderData : <></>)}
    </Grid>
    <Grid container item sm={6}>
        {previewData.slice(0, visible).map((renderData, i) => 
            i % 2 == 1 ? renderData : <></>)}
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

The map function provides a second parameter corresponding to the index, so you can distribute elements across columns using that parameter. You could also easily reconfigure this to show the first half of your items on the left and the second half of your items on the right.

```
<Grid direction='row' container spacing={1}>
    <Grid container item sm={6}>
        {previewData.slice(0, Math.Floor(visible / 2)).map(renderData)}
    </Grid>
    <Grid container item sm={6}>
        {previewData.slice(Math.Ceil(visible / 2), visible).map(renderData)}
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thank you, I hadn’t thought of splitting the map with the second argument. I appreciate your insight.

Comment: Great! If this helped solve your problem could you please mark the answer as correct? Thanks.